# Populating drop down with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following table `bookAssignment`:

```
ID   Group   OFFICE  name  FKOffice     FKGroup
---------------------------
1    Test1      X   West     1          1
2    Test3      Y   North    2          2
3    Test1      Z   South    3          1
4    Test1      P   South    4          1
```

I have around 3000 rows in this table where ID is unique and primary key. GROUP and Office has lot of repeated value.

I have another table for Office and Group

```
tblOffice

OfficeID    OfficeName
1            X
2            Y
3            Z
4            P

tblGroup

GroupID     GroupName
1            Test1
2            Test3
3            Test6
```

There is a relationship between BookAssignment table and tblGroup and tblOffice. FKOffice and FKGroup are the foreign keys in BookAssignment table.

I have the following model class:

```
 public partial class bookAssignment_new
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Book { get; set; }
    public string TechName { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OfficeList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GroupList { get; set; }
    public virtual GroupName GroupName { get; set; }
    public virtual OfficeName OfficeName { get; set; }
}
```

My GroupName Model is like so:

```
public partial class GroupName
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public GroupName()
    {
        this.bookAssignment_new = new HashSet<bookAssignment_new>();
    }

    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string Groups { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<bookAssignment_new> bookAssignment_new { get; set; }
}
```

My OfficeName Model is like so:

```
public partial class OfficeName
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public OfficeName()
        {
            this.bookAssignment_new = new HashSet<bookAssignment_new>();
        }
    
        public int OfficeID { get; set; }
        public string Office { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<bookAssignment_new> bookAssignment_new { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to populate two drop downs on my view with the Office and group.

Below is my controller code:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        
        return View();
    }
```

How can I make a Group and Office drop down in my view and populate it with Group and Office drop down values. Below is what my structure looks like:

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your are making two big mistakes.
First you are just creating instance instance on your model class i.e. `bookAssignment_new`. You need to populate that.

Second one is you are applying LINQ on string `.WHERE()` .Change Group and Office to list to apply any LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't put `OfficeList` and `GroupList` into the model. Assign it to `ViewData` instead.

Second, `bookassignment_new` is a class representing a *single* object. You probably have some way of populating a List of those. You can get values from that list by running LINQ query with `Distinct()` function.

So - your model in the controller is incorrect. That's why you are getting an error. Fix that first - and fixing dropdowns will be much easier

Comment: Please see my question. I tried putting the entire data in ViewData and removed the OfficeList and GroupList from the Model. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You are obviously not listening to what @Abhishek and I are saying. Remove the dropdowns; get the table working, and then handle the dropdowns. At this time you have a bigger problem with your code!

Comment: No sure where to make changes. Followed what you were saying. I removed OfficeList and GroupList from Model. I didnt show that in my question and then I called ViewData["DBMySkills"] = fromDatabaseEF;